# git lfs track fails on bare git repo

Tags: git, github, push, git-push, git-lfs

I'm converting SVN repo to a Git one. This finished succesfully and now I have a bare Git repo tham I'm trying to push to GitHub:

```
git push -u origin master
```

But this produces an error:

```
remote: error: File root/data/big_file.conf is 187.98 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

OK, so I decided to use lfs:

```
brew install git-lfs
git lfs install
```

Now while trying track my big files:

```
git lfs track "*.conf"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
This operation must be run in a work tree.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Clone your bare repo. The checked out files are called a "worktree".

Comment: How? `git clone new-bare.git` gives me `warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout` and the resulting clone is empty.

Comment: In new-bare.git you could type `git branch` to see what branches do exist. Then you could do `git clone --branch <branch> new-bare.git` .

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting: `emote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API....Everything up-to-date` but the GitHub repo is still empty :(

Comment: You can't use the GitHub repo until you have something stored in it. Use the original bare clone you made from svn to make a new repository that is acceptable to GitHub first. (Or of course you could use a service that does not set these limits, not that I know of one off-hand.)

Answer (score 1):

I hate answering my own questions but this is what worked for me:

```
brew install bfs
bfg --convert-to-git-lfs '*.{conf,log}' --no-blob-protection new-bare.git
cd new-bare.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push origin master
```